# Spatial join for checking whether a coordinate lies within a shape polygon

Tags: python, geopandas, data-frame

I've a database of coordinates that records lat,lon values in 2 separate columns as double.
I'm trying to map these points to polygons within my shapefile using geopandas spatial join, but I keep getting an 'AssertionError' on running the spatial join.

```
%sql

select distinct
a.x,
a.y
from common.ds_sys_wp_ppp as a
where a.x <= 68.685833075665

df = _sqldf

import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd
points = df.toPandas()

gdf_points = gpd.GeoDataFrame(points, geometry=gpd.points_from_xy(points.x, points.y,  crs="EPSG:4326"))

shapefile = "/dbfs/FileStore/tables/rasters/Shapefiles/india_administrative_boundaries_pincode_level.shp"

pincodes = gpd.read_file(shapefile)

sjoin_output = gpd.sjoin(gdf_points, pincodes, how='left', predicate='within')

sjoin_output.head()
```

I keep getting the following error when I run the sjoin_output cell:

```
AssertionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<command-969447486904127> in <module>
----> 1 sjoin_output = gpd.sjoin(gdf_points, pincodes, how='left', predicate='within')

/databricks/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/geopandas/tools/sjoin.py in sjoin(left_df, right_df, how, predicate, lsuffix, rsuffix, **kwargs)
    124     indices = _geom_predicate_query(left_df, right_df, predicate)
    125 
--> 126     joined = _frame_join(indices, left_df, right_df, how, lsuffix, rsuffix)
    127 
    128     return joined

/databricks/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/geopandas/tools/sjoin.py in _frame_join(join_df, left_df, right_df, how, lsuffix, rsuffix)
    316             left_df.merge(join_df, left_index=True, right_index=True, how="left")
    317             .merge(
--> 318                 right_df.drop(right_df.geometry.name, axis=1),
    319                 how="left",
    320                 left_on="_key_right",

/databricks/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in drop(self, labels, axis, index, columns, level, inplace, errors)
   3988                 weight  1.0     0.8
   3989         """
-> 3990         return super().drop(
   3991             labels=labels,
   3992             axis=axis,

/databricks/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in drop(self, labels, axis, index, columns, level, inplace, errors)
   3934         for axis, labels in axes.items():
   3935             if labels is not None:
-> 3936                 obj = obj._drop_axis(labels, axis, level=level, errors=errors)
   3937 
   3938         if inplace:

/databricks/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in _drop_axis(self, labels, axis, level, errors)
   3969             else:
   3970                 new_axis = axis.drop(labels, errors=errors)
-> 3971             result = self.reindex(**{axis_name: new_axis})
   3972 
   3973         # Case for non-unique axis

/databricks/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/util/_decorators.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    225         @wraps(func)
    226         def wrapper(*args, **kwargs) -> Callable[..., Any]:
--> 227             return func(*args, **kwargs)
    228 
    229         kind = inspect.Parameter.POSITIONAL_OR_KEYWORD

/databricks/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in reindex(self, *args, **kwargs)
   3854         kwargs.pop("axis", None)
   3855         kwargs.pop("labels", None)
-> 3856         return self._ensure_type(super().reindex(**kwargs))
   3857 
   3858     def drop(

/databricks/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/base.py in _ensure_type(self, obj)
     91         Used by type checkers.
     92         """
---> 93         assert isinstance(obj, type(self)), type(obj)
     94         return obj
     95 

AssertionError: <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

Attaching the tables.

Pincodes:

| gid | geometry |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | POLYGON ((77.13926 27.76213, 77.13982 27.76237... |

gdf_points:

| x | y | geometry |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 68.215000 | 35.500833 | POINT (68.21500 35.50083) |

df:

| x | y |
| --- | --- |
| 68.215000 | 35.500833 |

In total the df file has ~40M records and the shapefile has 19k polygons